# get extra data in Many To Many eloquent-relationships in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I create a table like this:

**posts**

```
  id title
```

**categories**

```
 id name
```

**category_post**

```
   post_id
   category_id
   custom_value
```

**in Category model:**

```
public function posts()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

with this command:

```
$category = Category::find(1);
$posts = $category->posts()->get();
```

I can get all of posts.

It is possible to return `custom_value` in `category_post` with each related post?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many - look at `Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [withPivot](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) function

```
class Category extends Model
{

  public function posts()
  {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class)->withPivot('custom_value');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withPivot()` method

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class)

public function posts()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class)->withPivot('column1','column2');
}
```

or

```
public function categories()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->withPivot('column1','column2');
}
```